# How to use the same session on Selenium & python

Tags: python, selenium

Im using Selenium to **scrape** some data from a website I signed up to, now every time I run the program it opens a new chrome browser and login to my account and eventually I runed into Captcha, how can I make it that it will open the same browser session with my account already logged in?

right now this is what I use:

```
    PATH ="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("website example")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Lookup for this, use  options.add_argument("user-data-dir=XXX" ) and use on init Chrome

Comment: So i added a profile and logged the website there, but everytime the program shuts down and start it again it requires login again since probably the website requires it?
Any idea how to keep the account logged in the website?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Guest user profile in your chrome driver.
Add this parameter to your chrome driver instance:

```
user-data-dir={UserProfilePath}
```

For me UserProfilePath is - `C:\\Users\\My_Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Guest Profile`

Comment: So i added a profile and logged the website there, but everytime the program shuts down and start it again it requires login again since probably the website requires it?
Any idea how to keep the account logged in the website?

Comment: Try to log in using a browser, restart the browser, and open the site again. If you are still logged in - you probably configured user-data-dir wrong. Since it should store your session data after the browser closes.

If you are logged off after browser restart - solutions are - resolve captcha (it's possible using anticaptcha services) or not to close browser window.